# Freeform: not recieving any submissions

Tags: solspace-freeform

Any chance somebody knows why this freeform form isn't working?
With not working I mean not recieving any submissions.
i cannot seem to figure it out because on one site it works and on a new site it doesn't.

The only difference is the version number of ee and freeform. On the old site its ee (2.7.3) / freeform (4.1.3) while on the new site it's ee (2.10.1) / freeform (4.2.3)

```
{exp:freeform:form
                        form:id="contact"
                        notify="claudio@maff.be"
                        form_id="1"
                        required="first_name|email|user_message"
                    }
                        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Contact from Nunc website.">
                        <div>
                            <label for="firts_name">Name*</label>
                            <input minlength="2" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="email">e-mail*</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""  />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="user_message">Note*</label>
                            <textarea name="user_message" id="user_message" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="sendButton"><input type="submit" value="Send" /></div>
                        </div>

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Rendered HTML ;)

```
<div id="form" class="section bg-grey">
        <div class="inner">
            <h2 class="heading size-2 weight-700 all-caps centered-text"><i class="icon icon-icon-circle ico-element"></i>enrol<i class="icon icon-icon-circle ico-element"></i></h2>
            <div class="box-form clearfix">
                <form action="http://dev.projectu-turn.com/?ACT=29" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post"><div style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" name="params_id" value="218" />
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="3a54070ec93939a2610d11a31e867ce6c289e539" />
    </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Contact from Nunc website.">
                            <div>
                                <label for="first_name">Name*</label>
                                <input minlength="2" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label for="email">e-mail*</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""  />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label for="user_message">Note*</label>
                                <textarea name="user_message" id="user_message" ></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="sendButton"><input type="submit" value="Send" /></div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does your rendered form look like?

Comment: Hey, I just edited to post with a render.

Comment: nn... no, I meant the rendered html code :P

Comment: oh :D Here you are @jrothafer

Answer (score 0):

Well at least your HTML seems to be rendering properly.

Your issue could be a couple of things.
Getting the simplest thing out of the way first...

Does the *name* attributes of your form elements match any of the field names of your new form? After working with EE and Freeform for two years now, even I sometimes forget to update these.

Apart from that, the only other thing I can think of that may be causing the issue is the ACTION id that the form is posting to.

Looking at your form, it uses an ACTION id of 29.

`<form action="http://dev.projectu-turn.com/?ACT=29" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">`

Take a look in your EE database at the ACTION IDs listed in the *exp_actions* table. Reading along the table entry, the ID should correspond to the *save_form* method present in the Freeform Module.

If this entry is non-existent in the table, it means that the installation or update of Freeform has failed. Fix the installation issues and everything should be working again as usual.